# Greater control of progress label positioning in pgfgantt

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, anchor

The following mwe is a bit of misuse of the pgfgantt package.  It is supposed to show the relative effort of various subtasks making up a greater task and the state of completion of each subtask, etc.  It is supposed to give a sense of the total state of completion of main task with disregard for timing of individual subtasks.

I spent some time improving the positioning of the labels which show the progress of individual subtasks to little avail.

Suggestions on how to place the progress labels beneath or above the center of the *entire* subtask (not at the complete/incomplete boundary) are welcomed.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{times}

\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0,0.57,0.81}%
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.51,0.81,0.79}%
\definecolor{blue_gray}{rgb}{0.36,0.52,0.63}%

% create a new command for a ganttbar entry
\newcommand{\ganttbarentryprogresscustom}[5]{%
\ganttbar[progress=#1,%
bar/.append style={pattern color = #2},%
bar progress label anchor=south,%
bar inline label node/.style={above=3pt}]%
{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[%
x unit=1.4cm,%
y unit chart=1.1cm,%
time slot unit=day,%
bar/.append style={pattern=north west lines, pattern color = cyan},%
inline%
]{0}{11}%
\ganttgroup[inline=false]{Task 1}{1}{10}\\%
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{100}{blue_gray}{Subtask 1}{1}{6}
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{90}{teal}{Subtask 2}{7}{8}%
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{75}{aqua}{Subtask 3}{9}{10}%
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `bar progress label node/.append style={anchor=north,yshift=0.2em},`, you get

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{times}

\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0,0.57,0.81}%
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.51,0.81,0.79}%
\definecolor{blue_gray}{rgb}{0.36,0.52,0.63}%

% create a new command for a ganttbar entry
\newcommand{\ganttbarentryprogresscustom}[5]{%
\ganttbar[progress=#1,%
bar/.append style={pattern color = #2},%
bar progress label anchor=south,%
bar progress label node/.append style={anchor=north,yshift=0.2em},
bar inline label node/.style={above=3pt}]%
{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[%
x unit=1.4cm,%
y unit chart=1.1cm,%
time slot unit=day,%
bar/.append style={pattern=north west lines, pattern color = cyan},%
inline%
]{0}{11}%
\ganttgroup[inline=false]{Task 1}{1}{10}\\%
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{100}{blue_gray}{Subtask 1}{1}{6}
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{90}{teal}{Subtask 2}{7}{8}%
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{75}{aqua}{Subtask 3}{9}{10}%
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]